# If $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^kc_k$, then $c_k=1$?

Tags: summation, diophantine-equations

Be advised this is a real soft question:

If $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^kc_k$$ Assuming $abc \neq 0$ must we have the following condition? $$c_k=1$$ for all $0 \leq k \leq n$

How do you prove it?

Comment: Does the equality hold for all $n$?

Comment: yes it does. There is no trap in the question. It is as simple as it looks.

Comment: I am just curious, given your accepted answer: You answered yes to my question above, which would mean that the indicated answer is incorrect. Can you clarify what you meant in your question so that others don't waste time answering the wrong question.

Comment: I think it's clear as day the OP doesn't understand his own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to generate a function that equates to $0 $ for all $0 \leq k \leq n$ as followed $$f(n)=(a+b)^n-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^kc_k=0$$ It turns out that $c_k$ does not have to be necessarily equal to 1 for that to happen. Funny, this only holds true for $n=0$.
One can quickly verify for $n=0$, we obtain:
$$f(0)=(a+b)^0-\sum_{k=0}^{0}{0\choose 0}a^{0-0}b^0c_0=0$$
$$f(0)=1-1c_0=0$$ which implies $$c_0=1$$
However, for all $n>0$, we have a different story. For instance, for $n=1$
$$f(1)=(a+b)-(ac_0+bc_1)=0$$ Where clearly we have infinitely many solutions for the following cases:$$c_0 = 1-\lambda b$$ $$c_1 =1+ \lambda a $$ where $\lambda $ is any integer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments below, if $n>0$ is fixed, then there is an entire non trivial affine space of $c$s that satisfy the equation. If $n$ is fixed, then the right hand side in the question is trivially a linear functional of $c=(c_0,...,c_n)$.

Comment: What part of my answer is incorrect?

Comment: $c_k=1$ is not the only solution. That was the OP's question in a nutshell.

Comment: The OP indicated that the equality holds for all $n$. (What does the $\gcd$ have to with anything?)

Comment: nothing at all, to be honest.

Comment: We are not incorrect, we all answered different questions, (the question I answered is the easiest). It tells you there is more than one possibility for the $c_k$'s when $a,b$ and $n$ are fixed. The problem is not clearly stated, that is the problem.

Comment: I did but I gave you your well deserved credit.

Comment: @dREaM, it is not true for $n=1$ as you stated below.

Comment: That's the answer, I've expected! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Clarification**: Based on the OP's response to my question in the comments above, I am assuming that the equation has to hold for all $n$. (If the statement is only true for a fixed $n$, then it is clear that the functional $c \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}a^{n-k}b^kc_k$ is linear and has a non trivial kernel for $n>0$, in which case the $c_k$ cannot be unique.)

Since $a\neq 0$ we can divide across by $a^n$, then letting $x={b \over a}$ we
can write the condition as
$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k (c_k -1) = 0$.

Setting $n=0$ gives $c_0 = 1$.
Suppose $c_k = 1$ for $k=0,...,n$, then
$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} x^k (c_k -1) = \binom{n+1}{n+1} x^{n+1} (c_{n+1} -1) = 0$, from which we get $c_{n+1} = 1$.

Comment: Be aware, we have one linear equation in $n+1$ variables $c_k, k=0,\cdots n$

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: My understanding (see the response to my comment above) is that the equation holds for all $n$?

Comment: I don't see an indication in OPs question pointing to a countably infinite system of linear equations. OP rather asks if the implication is valid for *each* $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: I am missing your point. The OP answered yes to my question above, so I am presuming that the equation is true for all $n$. If it is only true for a fixed $n>0$ then the set of satisfying $c$s form a subspace.

Comment: I should have written an affine space, not a subspace.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: down voted dREaM's answer because it is misleading. He wrote that it is true for $n=0,1$. Not correct.

Comment: Sorry, I was offline. Even if I don't agree, if OP is satisfied, then I won't further argue. I,ve mentioned some arguments and that's all.  Best regards,

Comment: Why the downvote again? It answers the question (whether $n$ is fixed or not) and is correct. This sort of pettiness really keeps me away from MSE.

Comment: @copper.hat: Hi, it's me again and I'm terribly sorry for erroneously downvoting your answer. It seems, it happend while I was leaving the session yesterday from my (too small) mobile. Please update somewhat your answer that I can upvote your answer. And once again, sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: Thanks for the clarification, it is no problem at all. The downvote as such doesn't matter, the reason does. I obviously overreacted above.